# Time based site redirection using htaccss

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 links:

```
http://www.example.com/private_link1.php
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/private_link2.php
```

What I want is to redirect them to a single location:

```
 http://www.example.com/site_in_works.php
```

This redirection must be applied **from 9PM-11PM** *every night*. If a visiter visits any of these links from 9-11pm then he will be redirected.

I read somewhere it is possible, but dont know how to do this and I know I can achive this with php and javascript... But for some reasons I want it by htaccess if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >2100
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <2300
RewriteRule ^private_link[12]\.php$ /site_in_works.php [R=307,L]
```

Comment: To use only 1 rule write `RewriteRule ^private_link[12].php$ /site_in_works.php`